# The derivative of the Gamma function, once more

Tags: derivatives, reference-request, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function

(In connection with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976454/the-derivative-of-the-gamma-function). My previous question was answered, and here is a modified version of my question.)

[The Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) satisfies the relation $z\Gamma(z)=\Gamma(z+1)$, whence $|\Gamma(z+1)|>|\Gamma(z)|$ whenever $|z|>1$ (and $z$ is not a non-positive integer). Is the function $|\Gamma(x+iy)|$ of the variable $x$ increasing if the parameter $y$ is sufficiently large? I am also interested in a description of the area where (the local version of) this property is fulfilled.

Comment: Are you aware of the explicit formula for $\log \Gamma$ and the complex Stirling approximation and why it is an answer ? That said, it could follow from a more elementary argument.

Comment: I am aware of the Stirling formula but I don't see why it answers my question.

Comment: There is a term $h \log |y|$ appearing in $\log |\Gamma(x+h+iy)|-\log |\Gamma(x+iy)|$ as $y \to \infty$