# Stirling's formula for normalized $\Gamma$

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function

Let
$$
H(s)=\frac{1}{2}s(1-s)\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right).
$$
Using Stirling's approximation for the Gamma function I would like to prove that
$$
\frac{H(1/2+it)\overline{H}(1/2+it+iu)}{\left|H(1/2+it)\overline{H}(1/2+it+iu)\right|}=\left(\frac{2\pi}{t}\right)^{iu/2}\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{u^2+1}{T}\right)\right)
$$
where $T<t<2T$ and $|u|\leq\Delta$. Do you have any idea how to show it?
I guess I should used the Stirling's approximation 
$$
\Gamma(s)=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{s}}\left(\frac{s}{e}\right)^s\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)\right)
$$
but then I get lost in the calculation and not able to get anything out of it. Thanks for your help!

----------EDIT--------

What I thought could work is the following: since we are normalizing our function to estimate we can use the fact that
$$
z=|z|e^{i\cdot arg(z)}
$$
thus what we want to estimate is basically
$$
e^{i\cdot arg(H(1/+it)\overline{H}(1/2+it+iu))}.
$$
To do so we use that $arg(z)=\Im(\log z)$, thus $arg(\Gamma(s))=\Im(\ln\Gamma(s))$ for which we use the Stirling approximation.
The contribution from the non-Gamma factor is easier to estimate and it should be
$$
(\pi)^{iu/2}
$$
Hence is remain only to estimate the Gamma-contribution.
To this end we use the Stirling's approximation (in an answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455306/real-and-imaginary-part-of-gamma-function) there are a lot of useful approximations) to get
$$
arg\left(\Gamma(\frac{1}{4}+i\frac{t}{2})\right)=\Im\left[\left(\frac{1}{4}+i\frac{t}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln(\frac{1}{4}+i\frac{t}{2})-\frac{1}{4}-i\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right]
$$
thus
$$
arg\left(\Gamma(\frac{1}{4}+i\frac{t}{2})\right)=\left[\frac{t\ln(1/16+t^2/4)}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\arctan(2t)-\frac{t}{2}+\mathcal{O}(1/t)\right]
$$
If I only use the first term of such expansion I get
$$
e^{i\cdot arg\left(\Gamma(\frac{1}{4}+i\frac{t}{2})\right)}\sim \left(\frac{1}{16}+\frac{t^2}{4}\right)^{it/4}
$$
and similarly
$$
e^{i\cdot arg\left(\Gamma(\frac{1}{4}-i\frac{t}{2}-i\frac{u}{2})\right)}\sim \left(\frac{1}{16}+\left(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{u}{2}\right)^2\right)^{-i(t+u)/4}
$$
Thus we I think it remain to prove is that
$$
\left(\frac{1}{16}+\frac{t^2}{4}\right)^{it/4}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{16}+\left(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{u}{2}\right)^2\right)^{-i(t+u)/4} =\left(\frac{2}{t}\right)^{iu/2}\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{u^2+1}{T}\right)\right)
$$
and that all the extra terms in the serie expansion of $\ln\Gamma(s)$ also go in the error term.

Comment: The [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Error_bounds) is $\log \Gamma(z) = z\log z - z + \tfrac12\log\frac{2\pi}{z} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1}{\frac{{B_{2n}}}{{2n\left({2n - 1}\right)z^{2n - 1} }}} + R_N(z)$ it is valid on any vertical lines/strip, it follows from approximating $\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)} = -\gamma+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{z+n}$. For $\Re(z)=1/2$ the real part is known from the reflection formula so look at its imaginary part.

Comment: I haven't really understood your hint. What I though could work is the following: since we are normalizing our function to estimate we can use the fact that
$$
z=|z|e^{i\cdot arg(z)}
$$
thus what we want to estimate is basically
$$
e^{i\cdot arg(H(1/+it)\overline{H}(1/2+it+iu))}.
$$
To do so we use that $arg(z)=\Im(\log z)$, thus $arg(\Gamma(s))=\Im(\ln\Gamma(s))$ for which we use the Stirling approximation.
The contribution from the non-Gamma factor is easier to estimate and it should be
$$
(\pi)^{iu/2}
$$
Hence is remain only to estimate the Gamma-contribution.

Comment: I edited the question: I have added what I have been able to do so far.