# Problem in Divergent series

Tags: riemann-zeta, divergent-series

Lets try to evaluate 
$$\frac{(-1)}{1^s}+\frac{(-1)^2}{2^s}+\frac{(-1)^3}{3^s}+\cdots$$
$$=\frac{e^{\pi i}}{1^s}+\frac{e^{2\pi i}}{2^s}+\frac{e^{3\pi i}}{3^s}+\cdots$$
$$=\frac{1}{1^s}(1+\frac{\pi i}{1!}+\frac{(\pi i)^2}{2!}+\cdots)+\frac{1}{2^s}(1+\frac{2\pi i}{1!}+\frac{(2\pi i)^2}{2!}+\cdots)+\frac{1}{3^s}(1+\frac{3\pi i}{1!}+\frac{(3\pi i)^2}{2!}+\cdots)+\cdots$$
$$=(\frac{1}{1^s}+\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{3^s}+\cdots)+\frac{\pi i}{1!}(\frac{1}{1^s}+\frac{2}{2^s}+\frac{3}{3^s}+\cdots)+\frac{(\pi i)^2}{2!}(\frac{1}{1^s}+\frac{2^2}{2^s}+\frac{3^2}{3^s}+\cdots)$$
$$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\pi i)^k}{k!}\zeta(s-k)$$
Now it can be shown that for $|x|<2\pi$
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}\zeta(-k)=\frac{1}{1-e^x}+\frac{1}{x}-1$$
Thus
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\pi i)^k}{k!}\zeta(-k)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}i$$
Suggesting that
$$-1+1-1+\cdots=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}i$$
Which is wrong of course, but not so wrong that is disagrees in its real part. What part of my derivation that
$$\frac{(-1)}{1^s}+\frac{(-1)^2}{2^s}+\frac{(-1)^3}{3^s}+\cdots=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\pi i)^k}{k!}\zeta(s-k)$$
is wrong and why does it give a $nearly$ correct answer?

EDIT:
Using the same method one can evaluate
$$-1+2-3+4-\cdots=-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{\pi^2}i$$
Once again incorrect but correct in its real part. Coincidence? I think not!

Comment: What do you mean correct in its real part? $-1+2-3+4-\cdots$ is divergent.

Comment: -1+2-3+4-...=-1/4 because -1/(1+x)^2=-1+2x-3x^2+... and setting x=1 gives -1/4=-1+2-3+...

Comment: So its Cesaro sum converges, not the actual series.

Comment: I think its Cesaro sum also diverges. But we are summing it in the sense that a+b+c+...=lim_(s->0) a/1^s+b/2^s+c/3^s+...
Using this definition, we even have 1+1+1+...=-1/12.

Comment: I see, I was misinterpreting. I wish I could help more, this is way out of my comfort zone; however, clearly the real part of those sums if falling out somewhere in your computation.

Comment: For those interested, see also this [very related post on Terrence Tao's blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/). I have been trying to comprehend it now for a few day. As far as I understand it shows a way to evaluate divergent sums as in the question, using [smoothing sums](http://www.tricki.org/article/Smoothing_sums).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting question! 
Your initial function is minus the [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) :
$$\tag{1}-\eta(s)=\left(2^{1-s}-1\right)\zeta(s)$$
Let's see what we can do with the function you obtained (for $s$ not integer) :
$$\tag{2}f(s):=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\pi i)^k}{k!}\zeta(s-k)$$

One problem with your derivation is that in your third equality $\,\displaystyle\frac{1^k}{1^s}+\frac{2^k}{2^s}+\frac{3^k}{3^s}+\cdots\;$ will be infinite for $k\ge s\;$ while the initial sum was convergent for $s>0$ making the equality (the exchange of sum order) problematic.

But a correct expression may be found. First some initial 'guesswork'. It seems that :
\begin{align}
f(0)&=-\eta(0)-\frac i{\pi}\\
f\left(-\frac 12\right)&=-\eta\left(-\frac 12\right)+\frac 1{2\sqrt{2}\,\pi}(1-i)\\
f\left(\frac 12\right)&=-\eta\left(\frac 12\right)-\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)\\
f\left(\frac 32\right)&=-\eta\left(\frac 32\right)+\sqrt{2}\,\pi(1-i)\\
\end{align}
Clearly we are not obtaining $f(s)=-\eta(s)$ but rather something like $$f(s)=-\eta(s)-\frac{(\pi\,i)^s}{\Gamma(s)}(1+i\cot(\pi\,s))$$ 
that may be simplified using the [Euler reflection formula for $\Gamma$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) : $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)\Gamma(s)}=\Gamma(1-s)$ and $\,e^{\pi\,is}=(-1)^s\,$ as :
$$\tag{3}f(s)=-\eta(s)-\Gamma(1-s)(-\pi\,i)^{s-1}$$
(numerically accurate for all the real and complex values of $s$ not integer tested!)
$$-$$
**ADDITION** (to thank Andrew!) Some pictures to 'show' what is happening.

The imaginary part of the zeta sum (formula $(2)$) for $s=x+iy$ is represented first.
Then the imaginary part of $-\eta(s)$ (formula $(1)$) at the same scale, the imaginary part changes in fact smoothly between $-0.45$ and $0.22$. The regularity of $\eta(s)$ in the complex domain shown is explained by the 'absorption' of the only singular part of $\zeta(s)$ (i.e. the pole at $s=1$) by $\left(2^{1-s}-1\right)$ to give $-\log(2)$.

Now the zeta sum $(2)$ contains not only the singularity of $\zeta$ at $s=1$ but also the transformed singularities at $s=2,\;3,\cdots$. The two last pictures show the sum $(2)$ but with only $2$ and $3$ terms respectively. The visual aspect of the poles is different because they 'rotate' with an angle $\dfrac{\pi}4$ and are vertically stretched.

Thus the point of the $\Gamma(1-s)(-\pi\,i)^{s-1}$ term in $3$ is to cancel all these poles at once ($\Gamma$ has poles at all the non positive integers) !

[image: four pictures]

---

Let's start this again with a direct generalization involving the [polylogarithm $\operatorname{Li}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) :
$$\operatorname{Li}_s(e^z):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {e^{nz}}{n^s}\quad\text{for}\; |e^z|<1$$

Using your method (with $\pi i$ replaced by $z$) we should obtain :
$$f_z(s):=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}\zeta(s-k)\overset{?}=\operatorname{Li}_s(e^z)$$
but get instead for $s$ not integer and $|z|<2\pi$ (or $\Re(z)\le 0$ only using the infinite sum for $\operatorname{Li}$) :
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}\zeta(s-k)=\operatorname{Li}_s(e^z)-\Gamma(1-s)(-z)^{s-1}$$

This result is given in [Wikipedia's polylogarithm entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Series_representations).
It appears too (with much more informations) in the chapter $5$ of an excellent article from Richard Crandall ($2012$) ['Uniﬁed algorithms for polylogarithm, L-series, and zeta variants'](http://www.perfscipress.com/papers/UniversalTOC25.pdf).
The part $2$ about the "periodic  zeta function" from the $1976$ paper ["On the evaluation of Euler sums"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.51.4916&rep=rep1&type=pdf) should be of interest too (consider $x=\dfrac 12$ and see $(2.7)$ to $(2.9)$ for your Bernoulli expansion).

The expression displayed is in fact the "Erdelyi expansion" for the polylogarithm which may be found in Srivastava and Choi's book ["Series Associated With the Zeta and Related Functions"](http://books.google.com/books?id=NBcSzUlaWWAC&pg=PA122).

I reproduce here the pages $28-29$ from Erdelyi's ($1953$) "Higher transcendental functions $1$" (where a more general formula $(8)$ is obtained and the case $s$ integer is handled too in $(9)$).
Let's just start with the definitions of the [Hurwitz zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) and the [Lerch transcendent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Definition) : 
\begin{align}
\zeta(s,v)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{(v+n)^s}\\
\tag{1}\Phi(z,s,v)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {z^n}{(v+n)^s}\\
\end{align}

$\qquad\qquad\Phi$ can be represented as a contour integral 
[image: Erdelyi 0]
[image: Erdelyi 1]
[image: Erdelyi 2]
[image: Erdelyi 3]

Where the Hurwitz formula $(1.10.6)$ is :
$$\zeta(s,v)=2(2\pi)^{s-1}\Gamma(1-s)\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{s-1}\sin(2\pi n v+\pi s/2),\quad\Re(s)<0,\;0<v\le 1$$

Comment: Where did you get these beautiful graphics ? :-)

Comment: @Lucian: I used MuPAD (in Matlab now). Other examples of the same 'style' [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138084/regularization-of-a-divergent-integral/139093#139093). Cheers,

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar "surprising" result when looking at the double sum just similar to your expanding into a double sum and reordering of terms. See [this link](http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ProblemWithBellmatrix.pdf)  When I encountered the problem I was astonished as you were here, and tried various heuristical explanations. However, an analytic solution was existent and so the heuristical introduction of the "infinitesimal" $\mu = 1/(-1)!$ compensated by $\zeta(1)$ like $\displaystyle w=\lim_{\delta  \to 0} {\zeta(1+\delta) \over \Gamma(\delta)}$ was somehow justified. Clearly, that use of $\mu$ should be replaced by a correct $\lim$-formula, but leave it for shortness of notation. *(Similarly, sometimes the bernoulli-number $b_0$ is interpreted as that same quantity when the bernoulli-numbers are rewritten in terms of the $\zeta()$-function.)*

I just inserted in your formula that infinitesimal $\mu $ formally in your formula to work with
$$=\frac{1}{1^s}
      (\frac{\mu}{\pi i}+1+\frac{\pi i}{1!}+\frac{(\pi i)^2}{2!}+...) \\
  +\frac{1}{2^s}
      (\frac{\mu}{2 \pi i}+1+\frac{2\pi i}{1!}+\frac{(2\pi i)^2}{2!}+...) \\
  +\frac{1}{3^s}
      (\frac{\mu}{3 \pi i}+1+\frac{3\pi i}{1!}+\frac{(3\pi i)^2}{2!}+...) \\
   +...$$
getting
$$= \\ 
  \frac{\mu}{\pi i} \cdot (\frac{1}{1^{s+1}}+\frac 1{2^{s+1}}+\frac 1{3^{s+1}}+...) \\
  +1                \cdot (\frac{1}{1^s}+\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{3^s}+...) \\
  +\frac{\pi i}{1!} \cdot (\frac{1}{1^s}+\frac{2}{2^s}+\frac{3}{3^s}+...) \\
  +\frac{(\pi i)^2}{2!}(\frac{1}{1^s}+\frac{2^2}{2^s}+\frac{3^2}{3^s}+...) \\
  + $$
where -if you let $s \to 0$ the first summand expands now to
 $$ {\mu \over \pi i} \cdot \zeta(1) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} {\zeta(1+\delta) \over \Gamma(\delta) } \frac 1{\pi i} = \frac 1{\pi i}
$$
and with that correction term you come back to the correct value in your final formula.
This heuristic *fumbling* is surely not formally correct but may give a hint how to repair your formula: I think usually we'll arrive at some additional integral-expression instead of the infinitesimal (likely by the Euler-MacLaurin-formula), or you could try to re-develop your formula using the Bernoulli-polynomials where the hack which I've indicated here with the $\mu$ is captured in the bernoulli-number $b_0$.

Sorry I can't do the complete process in the correct way, but perhaps this is instructive/helpful anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting approach Gottfried (I think I saw your question at sci.math in these days without having an answer concerning the $1$ difference...). Cheers,

Comment: If you look at the chap. $5.1$ of the $2012$ Crandall paper I referenced you'll notice that the author insists on the 'discontinuity in the correct analytic continuation' (that's my favourite approach too now!).