# The values of the derivative of the Riemann zeta function at negative odd integers

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I would like to know if the values of the derivative of the Riemann zeta function at negative odd integers are computed, i.e. $\zeta'(-n)$ when $n$ is odd. When I look at the page from [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) or [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), I just found the value of  $\zeta'(-1)$.

Comment: According to wikipedia the value $\zeta'(-1)$ is equal to $\frac{1}{12}-lnA$ where $A$ is the glaisher-kinkelin constant.

Comment: @Nicco: You are right. I misread the wiki page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact $\;\displaystyle\zeta(-1)=-\frac 1{12}\;$ while $\;\displaystyle\zeta'(-1)=\frac 1{12}-\ln A\;$ with $A$ the [Glaisher–Kinkelin constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant).

All this is given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Negative_integers) including the general formula (for $\,n\in\mathbb{N}^*$) :
$$\tag{1}\zeta'(-2n)=(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{2(2\pi)^{2n}}\;\zeta(2n+1)$$
Relations of this kind are usually obtained using the [functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation) (with $s \leftrightarrow (1-s)$ here) :
$$\tag{2}\zeta(1-s)=2(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)\,\zeta(s)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2s\right)$$
the derivative gives us :
\begin{align}
\tag{3}-\zeta'(1-s)=\left(2(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)\,\zeta(s)\right)^{\,'}\,\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2s\right)+2(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)\,\zeta(s)\left(-\frac{\pi}2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2s\right)\right)\\
\end{align}
For $\;s=2n+1,\;n\in \mathbb{N}^*\,$ and since $\;\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2(2n+1)\right)=0,\;\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2(2n+1)\right)=(-1)^n\frac{\pi}2\,$ we get :
\begin{align}
\zeta'(-2n)=\pi\,(2\pi)^{-(2n+1)}\Gamma(2n+1)\,\zeta(2n+1)(-1)^n\\
\end{align}
i.e. the wished relation $(1)$.

Now you were interested by the case $s=2n,\;n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ (with $1-2n\,$ an odd and negative integer) but in this case $(3)$ is not so simple (we will use $\Gamma'(s)=\Gamma(s)\psi(s)$ with $\psi$ the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)) :
\begin{align}
-\zeta'(1-2n)&=\left.\left(2(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)\,\zeta(s)\right)^{\,'}\right|_{s=2n}\,\cos\left(\pi\,n\right)\\
\tag{4}\zeta'(1-2n)&=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2\,\Gamma(2n)}{(2\pi)^{2n}}\left((-\log(2\pi)+\psi(2n))\zeta(2n)+\zeta'(2n)\right)\\
\end{align}

From this we see (for example) that $\zeta'(-1)$ may be written in function of $\zeta(2)$ and $\zeta'(2)$ and may thus justify the alternative formula for the [GK constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant) (using $\psi(2)=1-\gamma$ the [Euler constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant)) :
$$-\zeta'(2)=\zeta(2)\left(12\log(A)-\gamma-\log(2\pi)\right)$$
but all this shows only that there are no simple expressions for $\zeta'($negative odd$)$!

Other [relations (after $(4)$ in the link)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762066/derivative-of-riemann-zeta-is-this-inequality-true/762090#762090) may be obtained using the logarithmic derivative of $(2)$, there are too [some curious relations for $\zeta(3)$ and $\zeta(1/2)$ at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129706/zeta3-in-terms-of-derivatives-of-zeta-at-1-2-and-pi) but this shouldn't help here.

Hoping this clarified things any way,

Comment: Excellent post.  The lack of a simple expression for these values only makes them more interesting.  Fascinating numbers.  For example: every other negative odd integer value of zeta (-1, -5, -9 . . . ) is a negative fraction with a denominator that is divisible by 12, and the denominator 12 itself seems to repeat in a semi-periodic fashion as the absolute values of the results grow larger.

Comment: Thanks @emery! Concerning $\;\zeta(-1-4n)\,$ we have $\;\zeta(-1-4n)=-\dfrac{B_{4n+2}}{4n+2}\,$ linking your observations to the always fascinating properties of the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Arithmetical_properties_of_the_Bernoulli_numbers). Excellent discoveries!

Answer (score 0):

For where $m∈ℤ^+$,

$$ζ′(-2m)=(2m)!\left(∫_1^{∞}\frac{z^{-2m-1}}{e^{z}-1}dz+∑_{k=0}^{∞}\frac{B_{k}}{k!}\frac{1}{k-2m-1}\right)$$

$$ζ′(1-2m)  = \frac{1}{2m}ψ(2m)B_{2m}-(2m-1)!∫_1^{∞}\frac{z^{-2m}}{e^{z}-1}dz-\frac{(2m-2)!}{2}
$$ $$-(2m-1)!∑_{t=0,t\neq m}^{∞}\frac{B_{2t}}{(2t)!}\frac{1}{2t-2m}$$

where $ψ$ is the digamma function and $B_{n}$ is the $n$-th Bernoulli number.

Comment: Where did you get this?

Comment: In summer of 2021, I did some scratch work. I posted them somewhere. Are they interesting?

Comment: Probably not. I found the same result so wondered how you derived it.

Comment: @tyobrien Contour integral. I used the contour https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4767170/221315 here.