# On the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \ln n}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions

Does there exist a closed form for the series

$$\mathcal{S} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \ln n}{n^2}$$

Of course it is just $\eta'(2)$ where $\eta$ is the eta Dirichlet function. Wolfram Alpha does not return a result. On the other hand we are all aware of $\zeta'(2)$ which involves Glashier - Kinkelin constant.

How about this one?

Comment: $$\eta'(2) = 1/12 π^2 ( \gamma - 12 \log(A) + \log(4 π))$$

Comment: Thanks Z !! However it is strange that this closed form is not mentioned nor in  Wiki nor in Wolfram Wolrd!

Comment: See here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fds+DirichletEta(s)+,+s%3D2

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Thank you!

Comment: That might be useful as well https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210129/how-can-we-prove-that-2e2-int-0-infty-x-ln-x-over-1-e2e-pix-mathrm/2210655#2210655.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If
$$\eta(s)=1-\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}-\frac1{4^s}+\cdots$$
then
$$\eta(s)=\zeta(s)\left(1-\frac{2}{2^s}\right).$$
Therefore $\eta'(2)$ can be written explicitly in terms of $\zeta'(2)$.