# Beautiful closed form of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2(k+1)^2}\int_0^1\ln (k+1-k^x)+2\ln (1+k^x)dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, summation, special-functions, closed-form

While evaluating the following the integral which I found here in [brilliant](https://brilliant.org/problems/what-substitution-is-ideal-here/)

> $$\int_0^1\ln(4-3^x)+\ln(1+3^x)dx$$

I conjectured the general variant of the aforementioned integral as

> $$\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2(k+1)^2}\int_0^1\ln (k+1-k^x)+2\ln (1+k^x)dx=\eta(2)\ln\left(\frac{4e^{\gamma}\pi}{A^{12}}\right)\end{aligned},$$

where $\eta(.)$ is [Dirichlet eta funtion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function), $A$ is [Glashier-kinkelin constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html), $\gamma$ is [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and $e$ is [Euler-number](https://brilliant.org/wiki/eulers-number/).

*Is the closed form obtained correct?*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I have managed to explain the simplifications.

We claim
$$
\int_0^1\log(k+1-k^x)+2\log(1+k^x)\,dx=2\log(k+1)
$$Indeed, if this is the case, we are left with the sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1} \log(k+1)}{(k+1)^2}=\eta'(2)=\eta(2)\left(\gamma+\log\left(\frac{4\pi}{A^{12}}\right)\right);
$$this can be shown, for instance, on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2241508) MSE post. Now we have to prove the claim. We have
$$
\int _0^1 \log(k+1-k^x)\,dx =\log(k+1)+ \frac{\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right) }{\log (k)};
$$
$$
2\int _0^1 \log(1+k^x)\,dx =-\frac{2 \text{Li}_2(-k)+\frac{\pi ^2}{6}}{ \log (k)};
$$Combining, we have
$$\int _0^1 \log(k+1-k^x)+2\log(1+x^k)\,dx $$
$$
=\log(k+1)+\underbrace{\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)-2 \text{Li}_2(-k)-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}}{\log (k)}}_{\color{red}{L(k)}}
$$Let's show $L(k)=\log(k+1)$. We will use two functional identities which can be found [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog2/17/01/01/). First, we'll use Euler's reflection formula to eliminate $\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)$:
$$
\text{Li}_2(z)=-\text{Li}_2(1-z)-\log (1-z) \log (z)+\frac{\pi ^2}{6}; 
$$
$$
L(k) = \frac{-2 \text{Li}_2(-k)+2 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)+\log \left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right) \log
   \left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)-\frac{\pi ^2}{3}}{\log(k)}
$$
Next, use an inversion formula, valid for $\Re(z)\le 0$ with $z=-k$:
$$\text{Li}_2(z)=\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log (1-z) \log
   \left(\frac{1-z}{z^2}\right)-\frac{\pi ^2}{6};
$$
$$
L(k) = \frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)-\log (k+1) \log
   \left(\frac{k+1}{k^2}\right)}{\log(k)}
$$
$$
 = \frac{ \log (k+1)\log \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)+\log (k+1) \log \left(\frac{k^2}{k+1}\right)}{\log(k)}
$$
$$
 = \frac{ \log (k+1)\log \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\cdot \frac{k^2}{k+1}\right)}{\log(k)}
$$
$$
=\log(k+1),
$$as was to be shown.

Comment: To simplify the last result I  had to using the  certain dilogarithm identity from [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence's_function) that reduces the to (interestingly) to $ \ln(n^2)$.  Thank you for the reference for the sum(  I got  alternative ways to solve it). :) :)